# Analyzing protein sequences with the ProtParam module

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I'm fairly new with Biopython. Right now, I'm trying to compute protein parameters from several protein sequences (more than 100) in fasta format. However, I've found difficult to parse the sequences correctly.
This is the code im using:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
input_file = open ("/Users/matias/Documents/Python/DOE.fasta", "r")
for record in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta"):
    my_seq = str(record.seq)
    analyse = ProteinAnalysis(my_seq)
    print(analyse.molecular_weight())
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/Bio/SeqUtils/__init__.py", line 438, in molecular_weight
    weight = sum(weight_table[x] for x in seq) - (len(seq) - 1) * water
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqUtils/__init__.py", line 438, in <genexpr>
    weight = sum(weight_table[x] for x in seq) - (len(seq) - 1) * water
KeyError: '\\'
```

Printing each sequence as string shows me every seq has a "\" at the end, but so far I haven't been able to remove it. Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That really shouldn't be there in your file, but if you can't get a clean input file, you can use `my_seq = str(record.seq).rstrip('\\')` to remove it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that code, but, it seems that all the entries have an "\", except the last one. 
I fixed the problem by converting my sequences in this website: https://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/sequence/FORMAT_CONVERSION/form.html.
It seems that in some step when I was retrieving the sequences I added that symbols.

Comment: @MatGut yeah, cleaning it from the start is best.  However, the suggested code only strips the "\" on lines that have it and will leave others unchanged, so it should be robust to the situation you describe.